# ipython throws EOFError

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu, ipython, eoferror

I went to run ipython today on my Ubuntu 14.04 machine and ipython would not run.  I got the following error output.

```
selah@selah-OptiPlex-9020:~$ ipython
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/ipython", line 7, in <module>
    from IPython import start_ipython
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/__init__.py", line 45, in <module>
    from .config.loader import Config
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/config/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .application import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/config/application.py", line 17, in <module>
    from IPython.external.decorator import decorator
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/external/decorator/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from decorator import *
EOFError: EOF read where object expected
```

I can't think of anything obvious that I have installed or otherwise done to my system that has caused this... but it's possible that I might have.  Any advice on how to investigate or fix?

Answer (score 0):

not sure if you have solved this yet, but the following command fixed it for me

```
conda upgrade ipython
```